# Mouse Click vs Mouse double Click conflict in c#

Tags: c#, mouseclick-event

I have problem with event mouse click vs mouse double click.
I want to use event mouse click and mouse double click in my Label. when i put these two events, mouse Click fire the first and mouse double click not fire.
Here is code:

```
private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is Click");
    }
private void label1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is Double");
    }
```

Comment: Comment out the first `MessageBox` and you'll see the double click fires too, you are just interrupting it with the message box.

Comment: Yes double click work if i remove meesagebox in mouse click event. But Mouse click still fire. I just want to seperate both of them.

Comment: Think about that, a double click is two "clicks" chained together. If you want to separate them you need to delay the "MouseClick" to determine if another click happens or not (within some period of time). [Microsoft even wrote an article about distinguishing the two here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-distinguish-between-clicks-and-double-clicks)

Comment: Thank you Ron Beyer. I will try